# Getting Errors When Using Google Search API on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-search-api

I'm trying to run a Google Search API on Python, specifically this one: https://github.com/abenassi/Google-Search-API.

When I try to test it out by running this code on Sublime Text 3,

```py
from google import google
num_page = 1
search_results = google.search("This is my query", num_page)
for result in search_results:
    print(result.description)
```

I get a lot of errors, as shown below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1400, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 814, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1068, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/fake_useragent/utils.py", line 67, in get
    context=context,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1361, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/fake_useragent/utils.py", line 154, in load
    for item in get_browsers(verify_ssl=verify_ssl):
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/fake_useragent/utils.py", line 97, in get_browsers
    html = get(settings.BROWSERS_STATS_PAGE, verify_ssl=verify_ssl)
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/fake_useragent/utils.py", line 84, in get
    raise FakeUserAgentError('Maximum amount of retries reached')
fake_useragent.errors.FakeUserAgentError: Maximum amount of retries reached
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1400, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 814, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1068, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/fake_useragent/utils.py", line 67, in get
    context=context,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1361, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/fake_useragent/utils.py", line 154, in load
    for item in get_browsers(verify_ssl=verify_ssl):
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/fake_useragent/utils.py", line 97, in get_browsers
    html = get(settings.BROWSERS_STATS_PAGE, verify_ssl=verify_ssl)
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/fake_useragent/utils.py", line 84, in get
    raise FakeUserAgentError('Maximum amount of retries reached')
fake_useragent.errors.FakeUserAgentError: Maximum amount of retries reached

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1400, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 814, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1068, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/fake_useragent/utils.py", line 67, in get
    context=context,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1361, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/first.py", line 7, in <module>
    search_results = google.search("This is my query", num_page)
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/google/modules/standard_search.py", line 70, in search
    html = get_html(url)
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/google/modules/utils.py", line 432, in get_html
    ua = UserAgent()
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/fake_useragent/fake.py", line 69, in __init__
    self.load()
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/fake_useragent/fake.py", line 78, in load
    verify_ssl=self.verify_ssl,
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/fake_useragent/utils.py", line 250, in load_cached
    update(path, use_cache_server=use_cache_server, verify_ssl=verify_ssl)
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/fake_useragent/utils.py", line 245, in update
    write(path, load(use_cache_server=use_cache_server, verify_ssl=verify_ssl))
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/fake_useragent/utils.py", line 189, in load
    verify_ssl=verify_ssl,
  File "/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/fake_useragent/utils.py", line 84, in get
    raise FakeUserAgentError('Maximum amount of retries reached')
fake_useragent.errors.FakeUserAgentError: Maximum amount of retries reached
```

What do I need to do to get rid of these errors and get the Google Search API working?

Answer (score 1):

fake_useragent is only to mimic as a user agent but not official. Hence it throws error when detected. For the most recent call lost I did the following:

1. pip3 install fake_useragent --upgrade
2. ua = UserAgent(use_cache_server = False, verify_ssl=False) #Very important step, after this step you can write your code
3. ua = UserAgent() #creating object of UserAgent in my case
   header = {'user-agent': ua.chrome}  #accessing
   print(ua.chrome)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the official API so google is probably detecting that you are scraping their content "FakeUserAgentError". Try using the official [API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview)(you get 100 free searches a day). Then try something like this [here](https://cmsdk.com/python/programmatically-searching-google-in-python-using-custom-search.html)

Answer (score 0):

I tried `UserAgent(use_cache_server = False, verify_ssl=False)` but didn't work.

Upgrading the version to `0.1.13` worked for me.

```
pip3 install fake-useragent==0.1.13
```

I tried `pip install fake-useragent -U` but it somehow didn't upgrade the package correctly.

From the package owner: https://github.com/fake-useragent/fake-useragent/pull/136#issuecomment-1302431518